# Ways of keeping ANTLR4 grammar target independent

Tags: antlr4

I'm writing a grammar for C++ target, however I'd like to keep it working with Java as well since ANTLR comes with great tools that work for grammars with Java target. The book (*"The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference"*) says that the way of achieving target independence is to use listeners and/or visitors. There is one problem though. Any predicate, local variable, custom constructor, custom token class etc. that I might need introduces target language dependence that cannot be removed, at least according to the information I took from the book. Since the book might be outdated here are the questions:

Is there a way of declaring primitive variables in language independent way, something like:

```
item[$bool hasAttr]
:
  type ( { $hasAttr }? attr | ) ID
;
```

where `$bool` would be translated to `bool` in C++, but to `boolean` in Java (workaround would be to use `int` in that case but most likely not in all potential targets)

Is there a way of declaring certain code fragments to be for specific target only, something like:

```
parser grammar testParser;
options
{
tokenVocab=testLexer;
}

@header
<lang=Cpp>{
#include "utils/helper.h"
}
<lang=Java>{
import test.utils.THelper;
}

@members
<lang=Cpp>{
public:
  testParser(antlr4::TokenStream *input, utils::THelper *helper);

private:
  utils::THelper *Helper;

public:
}
<lang=Java>{
public testParser(TokenStream input, THelper helper) {
  this(input);
  Helper = helper;
}

private THelper Helper;
}

start
:
  (
  <lang=Cpp>{ Helper->OnUnitStart(this); }
  <lang=Java>{ Helper.OnUnitStart(this); }
  unit
  <lang=Cpp>{ _localctx = Helper->OnUnitEnd(this); }
  <lang=Java>{ _localctx = Helper.OnUnitEnd(this); }
  )*
  EOF
;

...
```

For the time being I'm keeping two separate grammars changing the Java one and merging the changes to C++ one once I'm happy with the results, but if possible
I'd rather keep it in one file.

Answer (score 2):

This target dependency is a real nuisance and I'm thinking for a while already how to get rid of that in a good way. Haven't still found something fully usable.

What you can do is to stay with syntax that both Java and C++ can understand (e.g. write a predicate like a function call: `a: { isValid() }? b c;` and implement such functions in a base class from which you derive your parser (ANTLR allows to specify such a base class via the grammar option `superClass`).

The C++ target also got a number of additional [named actions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md#named-actions) which you can use to specify C++ specific stuff only.

Comment: Hi, Mike! I'm working on the same approach with function calls. I'll plan to use it for the new JavaScript grammar. The old one with ugly runtime-dependent and duplicated code can be found in the official repository. I'm going to upload it at least for C# and Java runtimes at autumn. Also, I have some considerations how it can be used for JavaScript and Python runtimes (as you mentioned at google groups they home some troubles with `self` prefix and other syntax).

Comment: Oh, an update for the JS grammar would be very welcome. Will it support latest ES6/7 features?

Comment: I'm targeting on ES6 features at first, these samples: http://es6-features.org/ A draft with universal function calls available at our Positive Technologies fork: https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/grammars-v4/tree/javascript-universal/javascript-pt

Comment: @Mike Thank you, that additional named actions look pretty useful. I've spotted some oddity though - while `@parser::listenerdeclarations` and all similar are placed in class public area and `@parser::listenermembers` and similar are in private area, the main `@parser::declarations` and `@parser::members` behave the opposite way.

Comment: Hmm, damn, that shouldn't have happen. It should be consistent. Can you file a bug report for that?

Comment: It bears noting that using the `superClass` option doesn't take away target language dependency, as different languages would still require different content in their `@header` section to import the superclass name.

Comment: @markt1964 ANTLR generates the appropriate import-type code constructs as part of processing the `superClass` option.